# constant factor of strassen's algorithms

Tags: algorithms

Many references say that the large constant term is hidden in the calculation of the time complexity of the Strassen algorithm.

I want to know how the huge constant term is constructed or how it is calculated mathematically. (assuming when n matrices are given)

You can add more matrix constraints to help with the solution.

Thank you

Comment: Here's a good starting point: https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/107.pdf.

Comment: There are also many papers with empirical evaluations of Strassen's algorithm. Shouldn't be hard to find.

Comment: This is a useful question! I intend to improve the algorithm used in Sagemath, an open-source computer algebra system. It will be great if someone can summarize the state-of-art research result so that developers can focus on landing the code.